# how to create hook for Nested Json in wpdatatables in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

i have wpdatatables installed on my wordpress website. i'm able to connect table to nested json link

https://wp.kvvzwaluwen.be/u15a-wedstrijden/
[table image linked to nested json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNWkQ.jpg)
i have the home id but i want to go a level deeper and have the homeClub -Name (this is in an sub array)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAEEd.jpg)

but to get on level deeper i need to call hook where value seperator is {

https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/creating-wpdatatables/creating-wordpress-tables-from-nested-json-data-with-json-authentication/

```
Use hooks to parse one more level deep in root path
If one of chosen root path objects contains keys that have an array or objects as values and you need to include them in a table as cell values, then you can choose these two hooks:

wpdatatables_get_one_level_deep_json_data_from_array_as_string and
wpdatatables_set_one_level_deep_json_data_separator
For the first hook that accepts 3 params

$deepParse – boolean – false by default,
$jsonURL – string – nested JSON URL ,
$tableID – int – id of the table
you only need to provide a boolean value true, like in the example below:

/**
* Parse one level deep in nested JSON structure
* @param $deepParse
* @param $jsonURL
* @param $tableID
* @return bool|mixed
*/
function parseNestedJSON($deepParse, $jsonURL, $tableID){
   
   //use only for tables that have specific json url
   if($jsonURL == 'https://swapi.dev/api/people'){
      return true;
   }
 
   return $deepParse;
}
 
add_action('wpdatatables_get_one_level_deep_json_data_from_array_as_string', 'parseNestedJSON',10,3);
If you use this hook then it will be used arrayValuesSeparator which is break tag <br> and all array values will be parsed in cell one under another.

If you need another separator then you can use a second hook that accepts 3 params as well

$arrayValuesSeparator – string – tag by default,
$jsonURL – string – nested JSON URL ,
$tableID – int – id of the table
where, as a separator, a comma is set, like in the example below:

/**
* Change array elements separator
* @param $arrayValuesSeparator
* @param $jsonURL
* @param $tableID
* @return bool|mixed
*/
function changeArraySeparator($arrayValuesSeparator, $jsonURL, $tableID){
   //use only for tables that have specific json url
   if($jsonURL == 'https://swapi.dev/api/people'){
      return ', ';
   }
 
   return $arrayValuesSeparator;
}
 
add_action('wpdatatables_set_one_level_deep_json_data_separator', 'changeArraySeparator',10,3);
```

i added second part in my functions.php but how do i get these values visible

i added code to functions.php but don't know how to get data
where do i call action

```
/**
* Change array elements separator
* @param $arrayValuesSeparator
* @param $jsonURL
* @param $tableID
* @return bool|mixed
*/
function changeArraySeparator($arrayValuesSeparator, $jsonURL, $tableID){
   //use only for tables that have specific json url
   if($jsonURL == 'https://clubapi.prosoccerdata.com/games/team/15'){
      return '{ ';
   }
 
   return $arrayValuesSeparator;
}
 
add_action('wpdatatables_set_one_level_deep_json_data_separator', 'changeArraySeparator',10,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `content` as the `rootPath` and then to use the hooks `wpdatatables_filter_nested_json_array` and `wpdatatables_filter_nested_json_rows_by_root_path` to move the values in the sub-objects into the main object.

There are probably other ways to do it. I am using a similar technique to create "computed" fields from other fields.

```
function filter_list_row(&$row)
{
    // do specific things to the rows here
    
    // move homeClub.name to homeClubName
    if (isset($row['homeClub']['name'])) {
        // Create a new key called homeClubName
        $row['homeClubName'] = $row['homeClub']['name'];
    }
}

// This function runs when fetching data for the table
function filter_nested_json_array($data, $table_id, $table_settings)
{
    // You need to have a way that this only runs when you want,
    // so perhaps via the table ID?
    global $my_table_id;
    if ($table_id != $my_table_id) {
        return $data;
    }
    foreach ($data as &$row) {
        filter_list_row($row);
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wpdatatables_filter_nested_json_array', 'filter_nested_json_array', 100, 3);

// This function runs when inspecting the data for table configuration
function filter_nested_json_rows_by_root_path($rows, $root, $response)
{
    // Should check if $root is 'content', I am not sure how to do this

    foreach ($rows as &$row) {
        $this->filter_list_row($row);
    }
    return $rows;
}
add_filter('wpdatatables_filter_nested_json_rows_by_root_path', 'filter_nested_json_rows_by_root_path', 100, 3);
```